# Проблемы, когда помогает только очистка кеша браузера

Tags: браузер, кэширование, веб-сайт

Кеш для меня тёмная тема, плохо понимаю, как это всё работает.
На практике получается, что вношу какие-то изменения в сайт, и вроде всё ок. И могу много месяцев, а то и лет подряд вносить изменения, и они отображаются. Но в какой-то момент я внесу маленькое изменение примерно такого же характера (стили там какие-нибудь подправлю) и всё везде обновлю и перезапущу, но версию вижу старую. И помогает только почистить кеш браузера.

Интересно, как браузер "выбирает", в какой момент "застрять на старой версии"? Это рандом, есть закономерность или к этому приводят какие-то мои неправильные действия? Если мне пришлось чистить кеш, значит ли это, что мои пользователи тоже будут видеть старую версию, пока не почистят его? И может ли быть такое, что у меня всё ок, а пользователям надо чистить кеш?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заголовок [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) это основной заголовок отвечающий за кеширование.
Ключем для кеша в основном является url ресурса.

Кешировать могут не только браузеры, но и проксирующие серверы или сервисы.

Если не делать специальных настроек сброса кеша в браузере, то это будет работать у всех пользователей одинаково.

Чтобы версифицировать js и css обеспечьте добавление к Url ресурса дополнительного параметра (например `/style.css?ver=1`) и при изменении версии меняйте в html коде номер версии.

Либо настройте свой web сервер чтобы при запросе ресурса отдавался заголовок ответа `Cache-Control: no-cache`

Оба подхода гарантируют, что пользователи получат именно то, что нужно. Но второй подход ухудшит производительность за счет того, что ваш ресурс  никогда не будет кешироваться и вашему вебсерверу придется всегда заново отдавать клиентам этот ресурс, а браузеру всегда придется его запрашивать.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ! Не совсем поняла про версифицировать, то есть я просто указываю `ver=` в запросе, а в самих файлах версия не указывается? Ещё сталкивалась с ситуацией, когда нормально отображается из браузера, где сайт вообще никогда раньше не открывался, а везде, где хоть раз открывался, была старая версия.

Comment: ключем для кеша является url, а не содержимое файла. Поэтому поэтому добавляя параметр вы его изменяете и браузер уже не находит этот url у себя в кеше и запрашивает файл с сервера. Параметр может быть любым главное изменить url и обеспечить его уникальность.